# Add a training after payment

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5

I have 3 form, the first is the form `students` with 2 fields (name, firstname)

[image]

Then, we have the form `payments` with 3 fields (date_encoding, price, fk_student)

[image]

And finally, the last form `trainings` with 3 fields (date_sitting, fk_student, fk_payment).

My problem is the form **trainings**, I can create a new record without the payment of a student.

[image]

Is it possible to block a record with an error message in the training form?

Here is an idea of my code for now.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_sitting' => 'required|date',
                'fk_student' => 'required',
                'fk_payment' => 'required'

        ]);

        $exists = Training::where('date_sitting', $request->get('date_sitting'))->where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->where('fk_payment', $request->get('fk_payment'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Training::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('error', 'duplicate');

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - just add an if-check inside the creation block.  If the user doesn't have a payment, don't create and return an error message.  You can do this by redirect like you have it, or you can even have a separate check via AJAX to just see if there is a payment, similar to the if-check I add below on `$payment`.

However, to keep it simple & continue as you have it, something like this:

```
if (!$exists){
        // Is there a payment for the student trying to create a training?

        $payment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first()

        // You may wish to add some kind of date check to see if they paid for a specific training

        if(!isset($payment)){ // No payment = block creation and return error msg.
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'No Payment, no training for you!');
        }
        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... But I have an error message `syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)` ?? maybe it's the `if(!isset($payment)){`  ??

Comment: No, I forgot a semicolon after first() in the line above that.  should be `->first();`  Try that.